# What does "occasional bowel movement" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a new comics book about Geralt of Rivia and there is a phrase in the dialog about his horse:

> Some food, room to run and the occasional bowel movement,
>   that's all she really needs.

What does *occasional bowel movement* mean?
I found the meaning of "regular bowel movement" and "loose bowel movement", but I still can't get the meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Occasional" describes the frequency of the bowel movement -- i.e. the horse has a bowel movement from time to time.

Comment: I see now, in the dictionary it was defined as *stool*, but in this case it is closer to *defecation*.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the entire sentence is to convey the idea that, while the horse has normal biological needs, those needs are reasonable.  It conveys the idea of a healthy and content animal.  Geralt of Revia clearly likes his horse.  I like the question, and up-voted it, because it is such a good example of when language translation is not quite enough to convey meaning.  Interpretation of the translation is sometimes just as important, if not more so.